# Why does grep -I or grep --binary-files=without-match return a binary file?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, binaryfiles

I have a binary file:

```
# file /tmp/43174744S.0601.Z
/tmp/43174744S.0601.Z: compress'd data 16 bits
```

Even `grep` detects it as binary:

```
# grep "" /tmp/43174744S.0601.Z
Binary file /tmp/43174744S.0601.Z matches
```

Now I want to exclude binary-files by the `I` or `--binary-files=without-match` option, but it still finds the file?!

```
# grep -I "" /tmp/43174744S.0601.Z
Binary file /tmp/43174744S.0601.Z matches
# grep --binary-files=without-match "" /tmp/43174744S.0601.Z
Binary file /tmp/43174744S.0601.Z matches
# grep -Il "" /tmp/43174744S.0601.Z
/tmp/43174744S.0601.Z
```

Is this a bug? Because other binary files are found / not found depending on the used option:

```
# grep -I "" /usr/lib/*.so
# grep "" /usr/lib/*.so
Binary file /usr/lib/klibc-abS-oVB3xeRN8SFypUWbQvR33nc.so matches
Binary file /usr/lib/libdmmp.so matches
Binary file /usr/lib/libmpathcmd.so matches
Binary file /usr/lib/libmpathpersist.so matches
Binary file /usr/lib/libmultipath.so matches
```

So it does work, but not for this specific file.

Note: Tested with "grep (GNU grep) 2.16" and "grep (GNU grep) 3.4".

**Update1**

I extracted the first 2 bytes of the file and it still happens:

```
# head -c2 /tmp/43174744S.0601.Z > /tmp/43174744S.0601.C2.Z
# cat /tmp/43174744S.0601.C2.Z | od -a
0000000  us  gs
0000002
# grep -I "" /tmp/43174744S.0601.C2.Z
Binary file /tmp/43174744S.0601.C2.Z matches
```

**Update2**

This is really strange. After creating a new file with the same content, `grep` seems to act correctly?!

```
# echo -n $'\37'$'\35' > /tmp/test
# cat /tmp/test | od -a
0000000  us  gs
0000002
# cat /tmp/43174744S.0601.C2.Z | od -a
0000000  us  gs
0000002
# grep "" /tmp/43174744S.0601.C2.Z
Binary file /tmp/43174744S.0601.C2.Z matches
# grep "" /tmp/test

#
```

If I use `cp /tmp/43174744S.0601.C2.Z /tmp/test`, its broken again. So it must be related to this file.

**Update3**

As requested the output of `hexdump`:

```
# hexdump -C /tmp/43174744S.0601.C2.Z
00000000  1f 9d                                             |..|
00000002

# hexdump -C /tmp/test
00000000  1f 1d                                             |..|
00000002
```

Comment: Can you do `hexdump -C /tmp/43174744S.0601.C2.Z`?

Comment: Well it clearly shows that files do _not_ have the same contents. I cannot explain grep behavior.

Comment: is `/tmp/43174744S.0601.C2.Z` a regular file ? what does `ls -l /tmp/43174744S.0601.C2.Z` say ?